# How can I have two tables side by side?

Tags: tables, positioning

Suppose I have two tables that don't have many columns (3, for example). How can I position them side by side?

Comment: This question is quite popular, but the answers seem to have quite some overlap, but lack a coherent comparsion of the pros & cons of the different techniques used: `minipage, subfig & subfloat, \quad (?), parbox, subcaption & subtable`. Is there a consensus of what's considered best, if both "subtables" also have some basic (not a fully-fledged one with the "Table 2.1"-bit) caption?

Answer (score 213):

Just put two `tabular` environments side by side. Add spacing as desired.

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
a&b&c\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
d&e&f\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

If you want to use `subfig` because you want them to have separate captions, then that is simple as well.

```
\subfloat[caption]{\begin{tabular}{...}...\end{tabular}}
\quad
\subfloat[caption]{\begin{tabular}{...}...\end{tabular}}
```

If you want two tables that are independent, and thus don't want to use `\subfloat`, you can use `\parbox`.

```
\begin{table}
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
a&b&c\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo}
}
\hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
d&e&f\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bar}
}
\end{table}
```

This is basically the same as before just that I've centered each `tabular` in a `\parbox` with an included caption and wrapped the whole thing in a `table`.

Comment: +1 to the the first option that is very simple and suited very well for me.

Comment: By the first option, `just put two tabular environments side by side`, they aren't positioned next to each other, if I'm correct?

Comment: how do i use captions for the 1st option ?

Comment: As @MusséRedi mentioned first solution does not work (at least for me). Solution using table and parbox worked fine.

Answer (score 99):

If you want two `tabulars` next to each other in a (floating) `table` environment, then you can use `minipage`s

[image: screenshot]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \caption{}
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            3 & 4
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
```

Loading the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package will allow easy customization, and will remove the `:` when the `caption` is empty.

If you'd like 'sub'tables, then you can use the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package which introduces the `subtable` environment (and a lot more); the `subtable` environment takes the same mandatory and optional arguments as the `minipage`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            3 & 4
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that in both cases I've used a `%` at the end of the environment to stop `overfull hboxes`  from the additional space added by the `minipage`.

Comment: Why would I want subtables vs tabulars? Of the two methods you describe in your answer, which is *better* (and why) ?

Comment: On a second glance: is the *main* (visible) difference between the two methods the way the "sub"-captions look (e.g., "Table 2" vs. "(a)") ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty yes, your second comment is accurate. It depends how you want the captions (and references) to look. It's up to you which you think is *better* :)

Comment: Is there a way to have the tables start at the same height if they are of different lengths?

Comment: @PeterM you could use `savebox`- see my answer to [Reasons for saving a box?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87199)

Comment: Perfect. Just for clarification, I preferred to delete % since it looked awkward to have two conjoined table.

Comment: instead of `tabular ` can we use `tabularx`?

Answer (score 17):

I don't know that this is the best way, but you could make a 2-column table with a single row. In each cell of the table, wrap one of your intended tables in a minipage environment. Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} &

    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            3 & 4
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment with the down vote; I might then learn something about what makes this a bad solution.

Comment: Er, it wasn't me. Fyi, your solution's more or less the same as the one set out in the `subfig` documentation section "Do You Need This Package?" So, except for the bells and whistles (e.g., decent `toc` handling), it's probably not too bad.

Comment: @Geoffrey: I did not assume it was you, nor does my comment suggest that I did so assume. (By the same token, yours doesn't suggest that you thought I did.) Thanks for the added info from the subfig docs.

Comment: He-he. Didn't think you did, just wanted an excuse so I could comment that your solution wasn't really all that bad :)

Comment: Sticking it in a minipage makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Does this not work? My first guess was to solve it in this way... so how come it got a downvote?

Comment: I don't know why it got a downvote, but for my eyes the code has some faults: It gives an overful hbox message as the \parindent is not taken into account. It doesn't do what it probably wants to do: the tabular are not centered in the line as they are left aligned in the minipages. Also a minipage + an external tabular looks like an overkill (one at least could certainly be dropped) and makes the code difficult to read and changed.

Comment: @TH.: sticking single `tabular`s in a `minipage` is indeed not very useful. However, if you also have `\caption`s then this is IMHO the way to go, if both tables are separate and not sub-tables. I prefer `minipage`s before the very similar `\parbox`es because the first can e.g. contain verbatim material.

Comment: Where should I add `\caption`? @vanden

Answer (score 14):

*Ceteris paribus*, you might consider the [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/) package. It is suitable for subtables and subfigures and combinations of these.  For myself, I've managed much mileage from it.

Answer (score 10):

As the solution for  tables (not subtables) side by side with the `floatrow` package is not mentioned here, I'll add it under the form of an answer to this [duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318870/table-side-by-side).

> You can do that easily with the `floatrow` package. I took the
>   opportunity to propose another layout, without vertical rules, with
>   `booktabs`. For your original layout I added some vertical padding to
>   the rows, with the `makecell` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, caption, floatrow, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}%
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad, captionskip=4pt}
  \begin{floatrow}[2]
    \makegapedcells
    \ttabbox%
    {\begin{tabularx}{0.45\textwidth}{|c| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
      \hline
      & Sensibilità [$\%$] & Specificità [$\%$] \\
      \hline
      $ϵ'$ & 53.492 & 77.906 \\ \hline
      $ϵ''$ & 46.753 & 61.587\\
      \hline
      \end{tabularx}}
    {\caption[Valori medi]{valori medi}
      \label{val1}}
    \hfill%
    \ttabbox%
    {\begin{tabularx}{0.45\textwidth}{|c| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
      \hline
      & Sensibilità [$\%$] & Specificità [$\%$]\\
      \hline
      $ϵ'$ & 60\hphantom{.000} & 80.487 \\ \hline
      $ϵ''$ & 54.545 & 67.777\\
      \hline
      \end{tabularx}}
    {\caption[Valori medi]{valori medi}
      \label{val2}}
  \end{floatrow}
  \vspace*{1cm}
  \begin{floatrow}[2]
    \ttabbox%
    {\begin{tabularx}{0.45\textwidth}{c *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
      \toprule
      & Sensibilità [$\%$] & Specificità [$\%$] \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
      $ϵ'$ & 53.492 & 77.906 \\
      \addlinespace
      $ϵ''$ & 46.753 & 61.587\\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}}
    {\caption[Valori medi]{valori medi}
      \label{val1a}}
    \hfill%
    \ttabbox%
    {\begin{tabularx}{0.45\textwidth}{c*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
      \toprule
      & Sensibilità [$\%$] & Specificità [$\%$]\\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
      $ϵ'$ & 60\hphantom{.000} & 80.487 \\
      \addlinespace
      $ϵ''$ & 54.545 & 67.777\\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}}
    {\caption[Valori medi]{valori medi}
      \label{val2a}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

2 tables side by side, with (or without) caption, **without new packages**: Just imbricate 2 tables! It is perfectly fine to have a table as a "regular" entry of another table

[image]

The top level table has 2 columns and 2 rows. The top row is the caption, the bottom row contains the "real" tables that you want.

See how `\\` and `&` are used after `\end{tabular}`

```
\begin{tabular}{ cc }   % top level tables, with 2 columns
caption 1 & caption 2 \\  
% leftmost table of the top level table
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\
\hline
\end{tabular} &  % starting rightmost sub table
% table 2
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
d & e & f \\
d & e & f \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add another answer to this question because I think this solution is more simple, for simple usages like putting two table side by side.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\title{Table side by side}
\author{Vincenzo Palazzo}
\date{02/04/2023}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Input and output transaction struct of Bitcoin Code.}
    \begin{center}
        \subtable{
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{TransactionInput}} \\
                \hline \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Name} \\
                \hline
                Outpoint & outpoint   \\
                \hline
                CScript & scriptSig \\
                \hline
                $uint32\_t$ & nSequence \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \centering
        } 
        \subtable{
          \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Outpoint}} \\
                \hline \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Name} \\
                \hline
                $uint256$ & hash   \\
                \hline
                $uint32\_t$ & index \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}   
        } 
    \end{center}
    \label{tab:tx_in_and_out}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```