# How to use table environment when using multicols

Tags: tables, environments, code

I am using the command multicols as it is the best option for me. However, I have to introduce a table and I want to addd a caption. If I use the enviroment table it does not work, the table disappear.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  We need more information in order to be able to answer your question.  Please add a small, compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that produces the problem described.  Then that gives a potential helper something to experiment with, without having to guess.

Comment: When trying to place a `table` environment inside of a `multicols` environment, you should receive a warning such as " Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols`
environment!.". The `multicol` documentation also explicitly states ".  LATEX’s float  mechanism,  however,  is  partly  disabled in  this  implementation.   At  the moment only  page-widefloats (i.e., star-forms) can be used within the scope of the environment".

Comment: As an alternative, you can try the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package and replace the `table` environment with the `center` environment, provided you want to horizontally center your table within its column.

Comment: @pdr99 please see if the answer suits the requirement

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Two methods

-- with the makebox and minipage  with tabular environment and caption

-- with the tabular and captionof environment since multicols does not accept normal caption

with inputs from --

[How to put captions below tables residing in multiple columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115469/how-to-put-captions-below-tables-residing-in-multiple-columns)

and

[tables side-by-side using minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/tables-side-by-side-using-minipage?lq=1)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
                \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c|c|c| }
                        \hline
                        i & 1 & 2 & 3\\
                        \hline
                        $V$ & 10 & 8 & 12\\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}        
                    \caption{xxx}
                    \label{tab:first}
                \end{minipage}
                \hfill
                \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
                        \hline
                        i & 1 & 2 & 3\\
                        \hline
                        $N_2$ & 1 & 0 & 1\\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                    \caption{xxxx}
                    \label{tab:second}
                \end{minipage}
        }}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \blindtext[1]\\ 
        { 
         \begin{center}
             \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
               \hline
               i & 1 & 2 & 3\\
               \hline
               $N_2$ & 1 & 0 & 1\\
               \hline
               \end{tabular}
               \captionof{table}{Lets see}\label{pinki}
                \end{center}
                  }  
                 \blindtext[2]
                 \end{multicols}
                \end{document}
```