# How do I "unlink" the rows in one column from the rows in another column?

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting, positioning, line-spacing

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[left=1.25in, top=1in, right=0.85in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ p{3in} | p{3in} }
\cline{1-1} \\
Cell 0-0 &  Cell 0-1 \\
\hfill Cell 1-0 & Cell 1-1 \\
\centerline{Cell 2-0} & Cell 2-1 \\
Cell 3-0 & Cell 3-1 \\
\hfill Cell 4-0 & Cell 4-1 \\
& \\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{tabular}{ p{3in} | p{3in} }
\cline{1-1} \\
Cell 0-0 &  Cell 0-1 \\
\hfill Cell 1-0 & Cell 1-1 \\
\centerline{Cell 2-0} & \bf{If I type in Cell 2-1 and it's too long, it'll stretch out Cell 2-0 as well, which makes sense. But how do I prevent this from happening? In a sense, how do I "unlink" the rows in Col. 2 from the rows in Col. 1?} \\
Cell 3-0 & Cell 3-1 \\
\hfill Cell 4-0 & Cell 4-1 \\
& \\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

## Question

I present my question/issue in my MWE. Here's a photo to help, just in case.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MWE Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[left=1.25in, top=1in, right=0.85in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{minipage}{3.1in}
     \begin{tabular}{ p{3in}|}
            \hline \\
           Cell 0-0 \\
           \hfill Cell 1-0 \\ 
           \centerline{2-0} \\
           Cell 3-0 \\
           \hfill Cell 4-0 \\
           \\
            \hline
       \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{3.1in}
     \begin{tabular}{ p{3in} }
            Cell 0-1 \\
            Cell 1-1 \\
      \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

I ended up creating 2 minipages next to each other with the help of this [Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/tables-side-by-side-using-minipage).