# Create n minipages side by side on the same line, fail informatively if there's a minipage "spill"

Tags: minipage

I'm trying to create n minipages side by side on the same line. In the following example n is 6.

In the example below, the line below the section title is supposed to be displayed, roughly as

```
Column A    Column B     Column C     Column D    Column E    Column F
```

but instead it is displayed as

```
Column A    Column B     Column C     Column D    Column E
                         Column F
```

with the minipage containing `Column F` spilling over to the next line. I set each minipage's width to `\xfp{0.99/6.0}`, figuring that this would give me a "safety margin" in case `1.0/6.0` as a floating point converted to decimal is slightly bigger than `1/6`.

So I have a few questions:

- Why is the Column F minipage spilling over to the next line?
- Is there a way to fix it so that the minipages are all on the same line?
- Is there a way of expressing something kind of like a "constraint" where, in the event that a document with all the minipages on the same line cannot be produced, the document will fail to render with an error message?

Here is the full document.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{xfp}

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{6 Minipages Spanning One Line}

\noindent\centering{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column A
\end{minipage} %
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column B
\end{minipage} %
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column C
\end{minipage} %
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column D
\end{minipage} %
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column E
\end{minipage} %
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column F
\end{minipage} %
%
}
\end{document}
```

As far as I can tell the suggestions in the related questions (given below) mostly have to do with stray newlines between tables (which are commented out in my example) or involve non-trivial objects like tables or lists inside each of the minipages. Neither question talks about having your document fail to render in an informative way instead of having a table spill onto the next line.

I've also tried adding lines consisting only of `\hfill %` after each `\end{minipage}`, but without any success

- [tables side-by-side using minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/tables-side-by-side-using-minipage)
- [Problem with side-by-side tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14324/problem-with-side-by-side-tables)
- [Putting Figures Side-By-Side Using Minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157222/putting-figures-side-by-side-using-minipage)

Answer (score 3):

You still have a space after your minipages:

```
\end{minipage} %
              ^ Here is a space
```

If you omit it, the minipages are typeset correctly.

To have the mini pages fill the entire line (due to your safety margin), use `\hfill` between the minipage.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\noindent\centering{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column A
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column B
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column C
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column D
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column E
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.99 / 6.0} \linewidth}
Column F
\end{minipage}%
%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question but an alternative proposal for side by side minipages. You can build them with a `tcbraster` or `tcbitemize` from [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\mytab}[1][A]{\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column #1}\\
\midrule 
a & b\\ c & d\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[enhanced, empty, size=tight, raster columns=6]
\tcbitem \mytab
\tcbitem \mytab[B]
\tcbitem \mytab[C]
\tcbitem \mytab[D]
\tcbitem \mytab[E]
\tcbitem \mytab[F]
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might try the `tabularx` package which, essentially, uses minipages to hold text. It also automatically calculates the width of the column based on the width you supply, `\textwidth` in this case:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{6 Minipages Spanning One Line}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXX}
Column A&
Column B&
Column C&
Column D&
Column E&
Column F
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample using tabularx]