# Two tables side by side placed ; need to to align vertical top

Tags: tables, tabularx, article

I've two table placed next to each other as mentioned [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side)

Brief copy of code is mentioned below:

```
\parbox{.2\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\textbf{Q\#}$&$ \textbf{Skills}$&$ \textbf{Your}$&$ \textbf{Correct}$&$ \textbf{\%of Stu.}$\\
$ $&$ \textbf{Tested}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{answered}$\\
$ $&$ $&$ $&$ $&$ \textbf{correctly}$\\
\hline
1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
11&11&11&11&11\\
\hline
111&111&111&111&111\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\quad
\parbox{.2\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\textbf{Q\#}$&$ \textbf{Skills}$&$ \textbf{Your}$&$ \textbf{Correct}$&$ \textbf{\%of Stu.}$\\
$ $&$ \textbf{Tested}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{answered}$\\
$ $&$ $&$ $&$ $&$ \textbf{correctly}$\\
\hline
38&38&38&38&38\\
\hline
39&39&39&39&39\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
```

Here tables are coming next to each other with vertical alignment = middle. It need to corrected as vertical alignment = top. 
[image: Image Here]
Can you please suggest option for same?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution: wrap a tabular environment around the two particular tables and use the optional `[t]` alignment parameter of `\begin{tabular}`.

*By the way: The tables are too large, but I did not address this issue!*

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}


\begin{document}%
\small
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\textbf{Q\#}$&$ \textbf{Skills}$&$ \textbf{Your}$&$ \textbf{Correct}$&$ \textbf{\%of Stu.}$\\
$ $&$ \textbf{Tested}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{answered}$\\
$ $&$ $&$ $&$ $&$ \textbf{correctly}$\\
\hline
1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
11&11&11&11&11\\
\hline
111&111&111&111&111\\
111&111&111&111&111\\
111&111&111&111&111\\
111&111&111&111&111\\
111&111&111&111&111\\
111&111&111&111&111\\
111&111&111&111&111\\
111&111&111&111&111\\
\hline
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\textbf{Q\#}$&$ \textbf{Skills}$&$ \textbf{Your}$&$ \textbf{Correct}$&$ \textbf{\%of Stu.}$\\
$ $&$ \textbf{Tested}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{Answer}$&$ \textbf{answered}$\\
$ $&$ $&$ $&$ $&$ \textbf{correctly}$\\
\hline
38&38&38&38&38\\
\hline
39&39&39&39&39\\
\hline
39&39&39&39&39\\
39&39&39&39&39\\
39&39&39&39&39\\
39&39&39&39&39\\

\hline
\end{tabular} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've two column landscape A3 page layout. Where out of two column, i've to put two tables next to each other. So \parbox{.2\textwidth} is very important. Some option mentioned is not working with parabox. I'm trying to create MWE; It'll be great if you've any other alternate option.

Comment: @PawanMude: The problem was that I did not have exactly this MWE ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I found it while searching for an answer to an identical one.

Anyway, an easy method would be to use the [positioning argument](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#parbox,_minipage,_and_pbox) of the parbox, `pos`. For example, you could align two parboxes like this:

```
\parbox[t]{.2\textwidth}{
...
}
\parbox[t]{.2\textwidth}{
...
}
```