# Aligning two tables side by side and adjusting spacing

Tags: tables, spacing

I read the similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side), but I cannot manage to adjust the spacing correctly.

Following the answers in the linked question, I wrote this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\bmin}{\textbf{--}}
\newcommand{\D}{\Delta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{%
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c l r}
        & \textbf{Risultato operativo lordo (EBIT)} & \textbf{480}\\
        \bmin{} & Oneri straordinari/finanziari & 80\\
        \midrule
        = & \textbf{Risultato ante imposte (RAI)} & \textbf{400}\\
        \bmin{} & Imposte & 120\\
        \midrule
        = & \textbf{Utile netto} & \textbf{280}\\
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{%
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c l r}
        & \textbf{\D Patrimonio netto} & \textbf{100}\\
        \bmin{} & Utile netto & 280\\
        \\
        \\
        \midrule
        = & \textbf{Flusso di cassa per azionisti} & \textbf{-180}\\
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

What I obtain is this:
[image: Tables]

As you can see they are misaligned: I'd like the rows to be completely aligned (above all the last midrule).

Comment: Do *one* table.

Comment: @egreg I thought about that, but then the rules are joined. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use one table with a mock column in the middle:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\bmin}{\textbf{--}}
\newcommand{\D}{\ensuremath{\Delta}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c l r c c l r}
& \textbf{Risultato operativo lordo (EBIT)} & \textbf{480} &&
& \textbf{\D Patrimonio netto} & \textbf{100}\\
\bmin{} & Oneri straordinari/finanziari & 80 &&
\bmin{} & Utile netto & 280\\
\cmidrule{1-3}
= & \textbf{Risultato ante imposte (RAI)} & \textbf{400}\\
\bmin{} & Imposte & 120\\
\cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{5-7}
= & \textbf{Utile netto} & \textbf{280} &&
= & \textbf{Flusso di cassa per azionisti} & \boldmath$-180$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh thanks! I didn't know about `\cmidrule`!