# Table side by side

Tags: tables, positioning

I'd like to have two tables side by side. How can I do that? These are the tables

```
\begin{table} [h!] \centering 
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|c|X|X|}
        \hline
        & Sensibilità [$\%$] & Specificità [$\%$]\\ 
        \hline
        $\epsilon '$ & 53.492 & 77.906 \\ \hline
        $\epsilon ''$ & 46.753 & 61.587\\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption[Valori medi]{valori medi}
\end{table}
\begin{table} [h!] \centering 
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|c|X|X|}
    \hline
    & Sensibilità [$\%$] & Specificità [$\%$]\\ 
    \hline
    $\epsilon '$ & 60 & 80.487 \\ \hline
    $\epsilon ''$ & 54.545 & 67.777\\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Valori medi]{valori medi}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Certainly not by using two `floats this way. You can use two tabular environments in the same `table` environment`, each one having a caption. And don't post such fragments only

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks both of you. I did it!

Comment: @Shika93: I was going to propose another solution when you question was closed; so I added it as a new answer to the question in the above mentioned link, where you may examine it if you're interested.