# Table next to table

Tags: tables

I have this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]


\begin{document}

%\begin{tabular}[h]{lr}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| p{2.2cm}| p{2.2cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Europa} \\
    \hline
    País & Ciudad \\
    \hline \hline
    España & Madrid \\ \hline
    España & Sevilla \\ \hline
    Francia & París \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabla de ancho fijo.}
\label{tabla:anchofijo}
\end{table}

%\hfill

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| p{2.2cm}| p{2.2cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Europa} \\
    \hline
    País & Ciudad \\
    \hline \hline
    España & Madrid \\ \hline
    España & Sevilla \\ \hline
    Francia & París \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabla de ancho fijo.}
\label{tabla:anchofijo}
\end{table}

%\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the two tables next[image]

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I have two tables side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2832/5764)

Comment: NO IS DUPLICATE!