# Place 2 tables side by side

Tags: tables

How can I easily place these two tables that I have beside each other?

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \small
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
%        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision} \\
%        \cline{5-6}
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        \hline
        \# tr samples & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k \\
        \# te samples & 8k, 26k & \\
%        \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \medskip
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:runtime}     
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \small
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
%        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision} \\
%        \cline{5-6}
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        E & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        F & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
%        \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \medskip
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:runtime}     
\end{table}
```

EDIT: I tried putting them under the same \begin{table} and \end{table} but they are still not side by side.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \small
    \begin{tabu} to 0.5\textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
%        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision with label shifted by t seconds} \\
%        \cline{5-6}
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        \hline
        \# tr samples & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k \\
        \# te samples & 8k, 26k & \\
%        \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \medskip
    \caption{Models trained and tested on the complete sequence as described in figure 3a.}
    \label{tab:runtime}  

    \small
    \begin{tabu} to 0.5\textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
%        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision with label shifted by t seconds} \\
%        \cline{5-6}
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        E & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        F & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
%        \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \medskip
    \caption{Models trained on the complete sequence (fig 3a) and tested on the truncated sequence (fig 3b).}
    \label{tab:runtime} 

\end{table}
```

I have removed all white spaces but it is still not working

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \small
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision} \\
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        \hline
        \# tr samples & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k \\
        \# te samples & 8k, 26k & \\
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:runtime}  
    \small\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision with label shifted by t seconds} \\
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        E & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        F & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        \end{tabu}
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:runtime} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Put them inside the same `\begin{table}`...`\end{table}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I tried putting them under the same \begin{table} and \end{table} but they are still not side by side.

Comment: In TeX an empty line means a paragraph break, so you should remove that as well. However I don't know if you can have side-by-side tables with `tabu`...

Comment: i removed the empty line and it is still not working. so how else can i make them side by side?

Comment: don't put answers into the question but `\begin{tabu} to \textwidth ` makes a full width table so you can not fit two (also the `\caption` forces a paragraph, you probably want two minipages each with a tabu and a caption)

Comment: dear god so what should i do ? I wrote 0.5\textwidth but it still doesnt work. Is there a code somewhere with 2 tables beside each other

Comment: firstly you should fix the example in your question so people can run it without having to guess needed packages (float and tabu I guess) also do you really need tabu (it is rather broken and unmaintained, and you could better just use a normal tabular here

Comment: i use tabu because its the code i copied elsewhere. latex has too many functions doing the same thing.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88054/586 for an example.

Answer (score 3):

This solution aligns the captions.  Aligning the centers or first lines is relatively easy.  Otherwise you may need to use `\raisebox`.

I also added a `\columnsep` gap between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]% 
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
    \small
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
%        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision} \\
%        \cline{5-6}
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        \hline
        \# tr samples & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k \\
        \# te samples & 8k, 26k & \\
%        \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \medskip
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:runtime}
    \end{minipage}\hfill% add gap of \columnsep between tabus and captions
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
    \small
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {  X[l] | X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c]  X[c] }
%        \hline
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision} \\
%        \cline{5-6}
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        \hline
        A & 0.143 & 0.143 & & & \\
        B & 1.518 & 1.518 \\
        C & 0.018 & 0.142 \\
        D & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        E & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
        F & 0.029 & 0.180 \\
%        \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \medskip
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:runtime}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the following table design:

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
                    >{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X 
                    >{\hsize=0.9\hsize\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{}}
\caption{}
\label{tab:runtime}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5em}} @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{@{} c @{}}{Precision} \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \midrule
A               & 0.143     & 0.143     &           & & \\
B               & 1.518     & 1.518     &           & & \\
C               & 0.018     & 0.142     &           & & \\
D               & 0.029     & 0.180     &           & & \\
    \hline
\# tr samples   & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k & 53k, 187k & & \\
\# te samples   & 8k, 26k   &           &           & & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
&
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:runtime} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5em}} @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{@{} c @{}}{Precision with label shifted by t seconds } \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    & 0     & 1     & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \midrule
A   & 0.143 & 0.143 &   &   &   \\
B   & 1.518 & 1.518 &   &   &   \\
C   & 0.018 & 0.142 &   &   &   \\
D   & 0.029 & 0.180 &   &   &   \\
E   & 0.029 & 0.180 &   &   &   \\
F   & 0.029 & 0.180 &   &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}       
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```