# How to draw Cayley tables side by side?

Tags: tables

I would like to know how to draw two Cayley tables side by side for a project I am working on. How do I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have tried so far? Also please specify the following: do the tables need individual captions (Table 1 and Table 2), do you want subcaptions (a)  and b)) and a common caption or no caption a all?

Comment: Please, be so kind and show us what you try so far (in form small but complete document)? Many of us don't know, what is Cayley table, so please show us an example.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [How can I have two tables side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2832/134144) as the actual contents/type of the table shouldn't make too much of a difference for the alignment problem.

Comment: I know how to draw a binary operation table (which is what a Cayley table is), but I don't know how to put two of them side by side.

Comment: Can you show us how you make a Cayley-table then? If you're just using a `tabular` for example, just add one `tabular` right after the other, without any blank lines between them.