# how to avoid the captions of tables to overlap for both table side by side?

Tags: tables, captions

I am trying to have 2 tables side by side [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side). However the title of the table is long and it seemed overlap/touching it. How to avoid it?

Overlap point as shown:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Experimental setup for testing testing testing testing testing}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption{Experimental setup for testing testing testing testing testing}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption{Experimental setup for testing testing testing testing testing}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            3 & 4
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I properly got what you need but since the two tables are `0.5\linewidth` it almost a sure thiing that they would overlap at the end.

Comment: @mxncbaud, I mean the caption of the table does a little overlap. The table does not. Even I had changed `\begin{subtable}{.25\linewidth}`. The `caption` of the Table do overlap

Comment: Ok, what happens if you add `\hfill` between the subtables ?

Comment: @mxncbaud I tried `\end{subtable}%
     \hfill
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}`. the same

Comment: you also have to reduce a little the width of your subtables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this somewhat close to your expectations ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
      \usepackage{amsfonts}
      \usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Experimental setup for testing testing testing testing testing}
    \begin{subtable}{.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption{Experimental setup for testing testing testing testing testing}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}{.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption{Experimental setup for testing testing testing testing testing}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            3 & 4
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using overleaf and it does not show the result as yours

Comment: @aan Copy and paste I've modified the code it's ok on overleaf for me now.

Comment: thanks! It works!