# How to center captions on neighboured longtables with the use of Minipages?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable, minipage, alignment

I am trying to place two tablex next to each other in my TeXstudio Editor. Luckily, the following post already helped me doing so:
[stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side/2836?newreg=b94abb79790641eebf185f02fb792614)

But I am having issues with my captions. They do not align with my tables. I use a combination of minigpage and longtables and my result looks like this:

[image]

The \centering command won't help out. At some locations I even receive error messages.
This is my working code so far (content reduced):

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}
    \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}
    \begin{longtable}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.18\linewidth}!{\color{black}\vrule}>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}|>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}}
        WBP & \multicolumn{1}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}|}{Min CWT (incl.)} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}}{Max CWT (excl.)} \endfirsthead 
        \arrayrulecolor{black}\hline
        MIN & 0 & 6 \\ 
        \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}\hline
        N & 6 & 45 \\ 
        [...] \\
        \hline
        \caption{A}
    \end{longtable}
    \arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}
    \begin{longtable}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.18\linewidth}!{\color{black}\vrule}>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}|>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}}
        WBP & \multicolumn{1}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}|}{Min CWT (incl.)} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.25\linewidth}}{Max CWT (excl.)} \endfirsthead 
        \arrayrulecolor{black}\hline
        MIN & 0 & 6 \\ 
        \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}\hline
        N & 6 & 45 \\ 
        [...] \\
        \hline
        \caption{B}
    \end{longtable}
    \arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{minipage}
```

I would very much appreciate a hint or even exact solution, how my captions get centered below the tables. Furthermore, I assume I could use \vspace*{-Xmm} to move the caption vertically, if necessary.

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards
DomHaw

Comment: Putting `longtable` in a `minipage` doesn't make any sense, that's just `tabular` with extra steps. `longtable` is all about being page-breakable, whereas a `minipage` can't be broken.

Comment: Correct would be `\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}\centering\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\captionof{table}{...}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}\centering\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\captionof{table}{...}\end{minipage}`. `\captionof` is provided by the KOMA-script class (`scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook`), the `capt-of` package, or the `caption` package (if you use either of these you don't need the rest, the most lightweight variant is `capt-of`).

Comment: do not just post sippets that can not be tested, post small complete documents, but as Skillmon says never put a longtable in a minipage.

Comment: longtable captions are centred by default so what exactly is your question, what do you want to change from the default behaviour?

Comment: @David. Sorry, I should have kept [...] out. Then the code should run totally fine. 
Unfortunately the caption is not centered as you can see on my screenshot. 'Table 12' and 'Table 13' are way too far right.
Yes, Skillmons answer sounds plausible and I am just checking it right now.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. the code is using longtable in a minipage so is definitely not "fine" but we can not run it as there is no `\documentclass` or `\begin{document}` perhaps I can guess which package you used to define `\arrayrulecolor`  (as I wrote it) but you should not make people have to guess.

Comment: @David: You are totally right. Also \usepackages and so on are missing. Sorry for the inconveniences! I did not want my post to become too long, but it makes sense to have everything on board.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks, your idea helped. I got rid of the longtable and used tabular instead. 
\begin{table}
   \begin{minipage}
      \begin{tabluar}
\end_all

Comment: `\begin{table}\begin{minipage}...` doesn't make much sense as well (except if you put both `minipage`s in the same `table` environment). If you want the tables to be able to float that would indeed be the correct approach.