# No brackets appear for subtable

Tags: tables, overleaf

I am new to latex and I am using Overleaf to write my document.

I have managed to get the subtables properly but have been unsuccessful in getting brackets for the subtables caption, for instance (a): X (b): Y. Instead, I am getting a: X b: Y.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} %multiple images in figure
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{enumitem} %Indent lists
\usepackage{siunitx} %SI Units
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} %Line after each paragraph
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}% for \textsubscript
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{boldline} 
\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
%\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{\setcounter{section}{#1}\addtocounter{section}{-1}\section{#2}}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
...

\begin{document}
....
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Bla bla bla. Something value:}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{:\SI{1}{\meter}}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
            Distance & Speed \\
        \hline
            6 & 10.00 \\
            5 & 10.00 \\
            4 & 10.00 \\
            3 & 10.00 \\
            2 & 10.00 \\
            1 & 10.00 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{:\SI{4.5}{\meter}}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
            Distance & Speed \\
        \hline
            6 & 10.00 \\
            5 & 10.00 \\
            4 & 10.00 \\
            3 & 10.00 \\
            2 & 10.00 \\
            1 & 10.00 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable} 
\end{table}
...
```

I have followed https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3):_Figures,_Subfigures_and_Tables and looked at [How can I have two tables side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side) but still no success. Any help?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you load the `subcaption` package?

Comment: You have problems with document preamble, not with showed code fragment. If I put it in `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
your code fragment
\end{document}` the `subtable` captions' labels are in parenthesis. Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Bernard Many thanks! Yes I have ```\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} %multiple images in figure
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{enumitem} %Indent lists
\usepackage{siunitx} %SI Units
```

Comment: @Zarko I have edited my code and added the packages I used at the beginning of the document.

Comment: The defaul format for subcaption labels is `[labelformat=parens]`, so, in my opinion, remove `labelformat=simple`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much appreciated, Bernard.

Answer (score 1):

- you have serious problems with your document preamble:

  - many packages are load twice with different options
  - order the loading of packages is wrong, you have clash between packages
- As @Bernard noted, problem is your definition of `subcaption`: instead

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
```

you probably looking for default settings for `subcaption` (see MWE below)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
          total={170mm,257mm},
          left=20mm,top=20mm,
          }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % xelatex
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}   % <---
\usepackage{array, boldline, booktabs, multirow}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Bla bla bla. Something value:}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{:\SI{1}{\meter}}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
            Distance & Speed \\
        \hline
            6 & 10.00 \\
            5 & 10.00 \\
            4 & 10.00 \\
            3 & 10.00 \\
            2 & 10.00 \\
            1 & 10.00 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{:\SI{4.5}{\meter}}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
            Distance & Speed \\
        \hline
            6 & 10.00 \\
            5 & 10.00 \\
            4 & 10.00 \\
            3 & 10.00 \\
            2 & 10.00 \\
            1 & 10.00 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll try getting rid of those unnecessary packages.