# Fitting 2 tables in a page

Tags: tables, minipage

I try to use an answer from:

[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side#:~:text=Just%20put%20two%20tabular%20environments,Add%20spacing%20as%20desired.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20use,that%20is%20simple%20as%20well.&text=If%20you%20want%20two%20tables,%2C%20you%20can%20use%20%5Cparbox%20](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side#:%7E:text=Just%20put%20two%20tabular%20environments,Add%20spacing%20as%20desired.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20use,that%20is%20simple%20as%20well.&text=If%20you%20want%20two%20tables,%2C%20you%20can%20use%20%5Cparbox%20).

For some reason I can't place it. It might be due to many packages that I have but I don't understand the errors and can't figure out what went wrong:

- ! Misplaced \crcr.\endarray ->\crcr\egroup \egroup @arrayright \gdef @preamble {} \end{tabular}
- ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\endarray ->\crcr \egroup\egroup @arrayright \gdef @preamble {} \end{tabular}
- ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\endarray ->\crcr \egroup \egroup@arrayright \gdef @preamble {} \end{tabular}
- ! Extra }, or forgotten $. \egroup \end{tabular}
- ! LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 157 ended by \end{tabular}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{tabular}
- ! Missing $ inserted.$ \end{tabular}
- ! Missing } inserted.} \end{minipage}
- ! Undefined control sequence.\endminipage ...\expandafter @iiiparbox @mpargs{\unvbox @tempboxa } \end{minipage}
- ! File ended while scanning use of @iiiparbox.\par<> ./Main.texI suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing meto read past where you wanted me to stop.I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,you'd better type` E' or `X' now and fix your file.! Emergency stop.<> ./Main.tex (job aborted, no legal \end found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:55848 strings out of 4792831377091 string characters out of 28630652178386 words of memory out of 300000072483 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000424000 words of font info for 61 fonts, out of 8000000 for 90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191111i,10n,116p,10601b,609s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Please explain to me:

1. Which package is the problem?
2. What do the errors mean?
3. What can be done for it to work?

**I'd add that I updated Texmaker and Miktex and have all packages updated**

Code with all packages and table:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,                       % Papierformat
oneside,                        % einseitig
fontsize=13pt,                % Schriftgröße
headsepline=.5pt,             % untere Kopfzeilenlinie
numbers=noenddot,             % 1.1.1. --> 1.1.1
parskip=half,                 % halber Absatz
captions=tableheading,        % Tabellenüberschriften
DIV=12,                       % Satzspiegel (KOMA-Script)
toc=bibliography,             % Quellenverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
%tocdepth=3,                  % Begrenzung der Ebenen im Inhaltsverzecihnis
%headings=normal,                           % Größe der überschriften verkleinern
final                                                   % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{esvect}         
\usepackage{cancel}         
\usepackage{framed}         
\usepackage{mathtools}  %needed to avoid \\ problems
\newcommand\PZB{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{PBZ}}}{=}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\normalfont 
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc} { <-> ssub * cmr/bx/sc }{}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}   

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}   % Formeln mit genauer Abschnittangabe beschriften.

\usepackage{trfsigns}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}  % Die Nummerierung einer Gleichung hinten anhängen.
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily\color{NavyBlue},
  stringstyle=\color{violet}\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
  emph={square}, 
  emphstyle=\color{blue}\texttt,
  emph={[2]root,base},
  emphstyle={[2]\color{yac}\texttt},
  language=c,%
  tabsize=2,%
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
  numbers=left,%
  numberfirstline,%
  breaklines=true,%
  breakatwhitespace=true,%
  linewidth=\textwidth,%
  xleftmargin=0.075\textwidth,%
  frame=tlrb,%
  captionpos=b%
  inputencoding={utf8},
  extendedchars=false, 
  literate={Â°}{{\si^{\circ}ree}}1
        {ä}{{\"a}}1
        {ö}{{\"o}}1
        {ü}{{\"u}}1
        {Ä}{{\"A}}1
        {Ö}{{\"O}}1
        {ü}{{\"U}}1 %
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[                    
  format=hang,                  % Einzug
  indention=-0.5cm,             % Einzugskorrektur
  ]{caption}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{tikz}                                                           % TIKZ-Paket
\usepackage{circuitikz}                                             % Schaltpläne mit TIKZ erstellen.
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,positioning}    % Verwende offizielle IEC-Schaltzeichen.
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{w}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{bigdelim}         % Ermögliche bessere Formatierung der Zellen untereinander.
\usepackage{booktabs}         % Ermögliche besseres Tabellen-Layout.

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={25mm},rmargin={25mm},tmargin={25mm},bmargin= {25mm}]{geometry}
\addtolength{\footskip}{-0.8cm}  % Fussbereich 0,8 cm höher, so dass die Seitennummierung höher ist.
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}   % Muss ganz zum Schluss geladen werden.

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}               % KOMA-Paket
\pagestyle{scrheadings}                         % Seitenstil
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\clearscrheadfoot                                       % Lösche alle Voreinstellungen.
\cfoot{\pagemark}                                       % Erstelle (zentrale) Seitennummern.


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Global caption}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \caption{equipment}
  \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{QTY} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
    \caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{QTY} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline

          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
          &              &                 &                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the extra `\end{tabular}` from your first `minipage` environment.

Comment: Unrelated, but please keep in mind that the `subfigure` package is deprecated. You might want to switch to `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `\end{tabular}` line #145 marked as `%    \end{tabular}  % REMOVE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`

Removing the dupicate line will eliminate all the compile errors  and answer your three questions.

[image: a]

This is the xl MWE

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[
paper=a4,                       % Papierformat
oneside,                        % einseitig
fontsize=13pt,                % Schriftgröße
headsepline=.5pt,             % untere Kopfzeilenlinie
numbers=noenddot,             % 1.1.1. --> 1.1.1
parskip=half,                 % halber Absatz
captions=tableheading,        % Tabellenüberschriften
DIV=12,                       % Satzspiegel (KOMA-Script)
toc=bibliography,             % Quellenverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
tocdepth=3,                  % Begrenzung der Ebenen im Inhaltsverzecihnis
headings=normal,                           % Größe der überschriften verkleinern
final                                                   % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{esvect}         
\usepackage{cancel}         
\usepackage{framed}         
\usepackage{mathtools}  %needed to avoid \\ problems
\newcommand\PZB{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{PBZ}}}{=}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\normalfont 
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc} { <-> ssub * cmr/bx/sc }{}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}   

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}   % Formeln mit genauer Abschnittangabe beschriften.

\usepackage{trfsigns}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}  % Die Nummerierung einer Gleichung hinten anhängen.
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily\color{NavyBlue},
    stringstyle=\color{violet}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    emph={square}, 
    emphstyle=\color{blue}\texttt,
    emph={[2]root,base},
    emphstyle={[2]\color{yac}\texttt},
    language=c,%
    tabsize=2,%
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
    numbers=left,%
    numberfirstline,%
    breaklines=true,%
    breakatwhitespace=true,%
    linewidth=\textwidth,%
    xleftmargin=0.075\textwidth,%
    frame=tlrb,%
    captionpos=b%
    inputencoding={utf8},
    extendedchars=false, 
    literate={Â°}{{\si^{\circ}ree}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {ü}{{\"U}}1 %
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[                    
format=hang,                  % Einzug
indention=-0.5cm,             % Einzugskorrektur
]{caption}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{tikz}                                                           % TIKZ-Paket
\usepackage{circuitikz}                                             % Schaltpläne mit TIKZ erstellen.
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,positioning}    % Verwende offizielle IEC-Schaltzeichen.
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{w}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{bigdelim}         % Ermögliche bessere Formatierung der Zellen untereinander.
\usepackage{booktabs}         % Ermögliche besseres Tabellen-Layout.

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={25mm},rmargin={25mm},tmargin={25mm},bmargin= {25mm}]{geometry}
\addtolength{\footskip}{-0.8cm}  % Fussbereich 0,8 cm höher, so dass die Seitennummierung höher ist.
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}   % Muss ganz zum Schluss geladen werden.

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}               % KOMA-Paket
\pagestyle{scrheadings}                         % Seitenstil
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\clearscrheadfoot                                       % Lösche alle Voreinstellungen.
\cfoot{\pagemark}                                       % Erstelle (zentrale) Seitennummern.


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \caption{Global caption}
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \caption{equipment}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
                \hline 
                \textbf{Name} & \textbf{QTY} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
                &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
%   \end{tabular}  % REMOVE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline 
            \textbf{Name} & \textbf{QTY} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
            
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
            &              &                 &                \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```